# Unable to understand how the while loop extracts the least number of coins with given sum

Tags: data-structures, dynamic-programming, arrays, coin-change

I was reading this classical Coin Problem ([7.1](https://usaco.guide/CPH.pdf#page=75)): Given a set
of coin values coins = {c1, c2,..., ck} and a target sum of money n, our task is to
form the sum n using as few coins as possible.

I fully understood the discussion until I encountered the last code snippet of the section [*Constructing A Solution*](https://usaco.guide/CPH.pdf#page=78):

```
    int first[N];  // N is sufficiently large

    value[0] = 0;
    for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
       value[x] = INF;
       for (auto c : coins) {
         if (x-c >= 0 && value[x-c]+1 < value[x]) {
            value[x] = value[x-c]+1;
            first[x] = c;
         }
       }
    }

    while (n > 0) {
       cout << first[n] << "\n";
       n -= first[n]; 
    }
```

My doubt is pertaining to the way array *first* is storing the coin denominations and how the while loop at the last is able to extract the required coins.

For example consider this case when I have coins of denominations {1, 4, 5, 10, 20}, with each coin available as many numbers as needed. So to form a sum of **22**, optimally I need one 20 unit and two 1 units. This is what the code gives as output, when properly coded.

But I am not able to undertand how this *first* array is storing the denomination values. So to understand this I printed out this *first* arrray and got this:

> 0 1 1 1 4 5 1 1 4 4 10 1 1 4 4 5 1 1 4 4 20 1 1

And I was more confused.

In short: please explain how *first* array stores values and how the **while** loop is able to print out only the required values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us take a look at line 3 and 4 of the following part of the code.

```
1       for (auto c : coins) {
2         if (x-c >= 0 && value[x-c]+1 < value[x]) {
3            value[x] = value[x-c]+1;
4            first[x] = c;
5         }
6       }
```

`value[x]` should store the least number of coins needed to form `x`.
`value[x-c]` stores the least number of coins needed to form `x-c`.
Line 3 means, if we take coin `c` *first* and use `value[x-c]` coins to form the rest, `x-c`, we will use `value[x-c]+1` coins to form `c+(x-c)=x`. So we can set `value[x]` to be `value[x-c]+1`.

Since `first[x]` is set to `c` at line 4, we can replace `c` by `first[x]`.
**Line 3 can be read again as, in order to use the least number of coins to form `x`, we can take coin `first[x]` *first* and then use the least number of coins to form the rest, `x-first[x]`.**

---

Let us read the while loop.

Initially, the target is `n`. Treating `n` as `x` above, we see that in order to use the least number of coins to form `n`, we can take coin `first[n]` *first* (so, we will print `first[n]` by `cout << first[n] << "\n";`) and then will use the least number of coins to form `n-first[n]`.

Now the target is `n-first[n]`. This is the same situation as the initial situation. So we will set `n` to `n-first[n]`, and repeat.

---

For example, when `n=22`.

Since `first[22]=1`, we will take coin 1 first.
The target to form next is `22-1=21`.
Since `first[21]=1`, we will take coin 1 first. (In fact, this is the second coin.)
The target to form next is `21-1=20`.
Since `first[20]=20`, we will take coin 20 first. (In fact, this is the third coin).
The target to form next is `20-20=0`. No more action is needed to form  `0`.

Comment: I understood the explaination! But there is improvement needed for the example part. It is first[22]=1, first[21]=1 and first[20]=20. Thanks.

Comment: I was using `{20, 10, 5, 4, 1}` as `coins`. Anyway, I just switched my answer to your version, `{1, 4, 5, 10, 20}`.

Comment: So, although it might appear obvious, I just observed that the values stored in 'first' depend on the arrangement of coins' denominations.